How to avoid artifacts penetrating surface when solidifying?
Trying noob here. I have complex 3D scans of objects that I am working towards 3D printing for onward sand casting and metallurgy. The scans are very hi res, but I wish to keep as much detail as possible as they will be printed at scale in sections that will be joint together. I am currently using the decimate modifier to reduce the burden somewhat.
I am attempting to thicken into a uniform shell of approx 3mm using the solidify modifier but am getting barnicle like artifacts pushing through the shell face due to the irregular surface and the normal direction of each face when solidified pushing through.
Is there a method to eliminate this push through? Or must I edit each case back through the face with a kind of extrusion in the opposing direction?
The example shown is a small scan so being able to have a efficient workflow will save me a lot of time.
Any help much appreciated








Hello, I guess you can try to clean the mesh with a remesh tool

It'd be interesting to see the face orientation view

Hi Allan, I have added an image in face orientation view. It seems to pick up some, but not all of the barnacle artifacts.

Hi Moonboots. I want to keep the mesh surface as it is if possible, rather than changing it.

Does one side of the solidification have to match the other original side?

Hi Labcat. No, the underside doesn’t need to match the face mesh exactly, just an approximate thickness. It may be better if the underside is slightly smoother / more uniform.
